# multiple writeStream with spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with spark streaming and I am facing some issues trying to implement multiple writestreams. 
Below is my code

```scala
DataWriter.writeStreamer(firstTableData,"parquet",CheckPointConf.firstCheckPoint,OutputConf.firstDataOutput)
DataWriter.writeStreamer(secondTableData,"parquet",CheckPointConf.secondCheckPoint,OutputConf.secondDataOutput)
DataWriter.writeStreamer(thirdTableData,"parquet", CheckPointConf.thirdCheckPoint,OutputConf.thirdDataOutput)
```

where writeStreamer is defined as follows :

```scala
def writeStreamer(input: DataFrame, checkPointFolder: String, output: String) = {

  val query = input
                .writeStream
                .format("orc")
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointFolder)
                .option("path", output)
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
                .start()

  query.awaitTermination()
}
```

the problem I am facing is that only the first table is written with spark writeStream , nothing happens for all other tables . 
Do you have any idea about this please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`query.awaitTermination()` should be done **after** the last stream is created.

`writeStreamer` function can be modified to return a `StreamingQuery` and not awaitTermination at that point (as it is **blocking**):

```
def writeStreamer(input: DataFrame, checkPointFolder: String, output: String): StreamingQuery = {
  input
    .writeStream
    .format("orc")
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkPointFolder)
    .option("path", output)
    .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
    .start()
}
```

then you will have:

```
val query1 = DataWriter.writeStreamer(...)
val query2 = DataWriter.writeStreamer(...)
val query3 = DataWriter.writeStreamer(...)

query3.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to execute writers to run in parallel you can use

```
sparkSession.streams.awaitAnyTermination()
```

and remove `query.awaitTermination()` from writeStreamer method

Answer (score 0):

> By default the number of concurrent jobs is 1 which means at a time
>   only 1 job will be active

did you try increase number of possible concurent job in spark conf ?

```
sparkConf.set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs","3")
```

not a offcial source : http://why-not-learn-something.blogspot.com/2016/06/spark-streaming-performance-tuning-on.html

Comment: I removed the await termination from the writer , and now I am getting a new error : ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 1 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down